# Button click inside repeater UpdatePanel problem

Tags: asp.net-core, webforms, updatepanel, repeater, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have button inside of repeater in a contentpage.
How can I use update panel with that?
I want to make that,

Button click inside a repeater triggers itemcommand function and after that not posstback refresh.

Best regards

Comment: Welcome at SO. Please give your code. See [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this result?

[image]

Microsoft officially gave some good cases, you can refer to the following:

[Specify and code handlers for the ItemCommand event of the Repeater control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand?view=netframework-4.8)